# ruby/mysql: query returns only one user instead of many users

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

I have one table with quotes which stores quotes from tradesman (price, comment, date the employer accepted this quote, ...), and another table with ratings (positive/negativ, comment, date the rating has been submitted, ...) of each tradesman. So, a tradesman can have 0..n quotes and 0..n ratings.

What I want to find out:

- how many ratings did the tradesman had when his quote was accepted by the employer?

My current approach:

- The 1st query ('quotes') is to find out the user ID of the quoters and at which date the employer accepted the quote.
- The 2nd query ('ratings') is within a block. For each tradesman ID, the query should fetch the ratings that are equal or simililar of the date the quote has been accepted.

Problem:

- The 2nd query gets only the ratings from one user, although it should get ratings from about 70 users. Anybody has an idea whats wrong with the query?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "mysql"

begin
  db_q = Mysql.real_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_db")
  quotes = db_q.query("
  SELECT q.user_id, q.accepted_at
  FROM quotes q
    INNER JOIN jobs j ON q.job_id = j.id
    INNER JOIN categories_jobs cj ON j.id = cj.job_id
    INNER JOIN categories c ON cj.category_id = c.id
    INNER JOIN users u ON j.user_id = u.id
  WHERE q.accepted_at IS NOT NULL
  AND c.id = 8
  ")

  db_r = Mysql.real_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_db")
  quotes.each do |quote|    
    ratings = db_r.query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE assessee_id = #{quote[0]} AND CAST(created_at as DATE) <= '#{quote[1]}'")
    ratings.each do |rating|
      printf "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", rating[0], rating[2], rating[3], rating[4], rating[5], rating[6]
    end
  end

  ratings.free
  quotes.free

rescue Mysql::Error => e
  puts "Error code: #{e.errno}"
  puts "Error message: #{e.error}"
  puts "Error SQLSTATE: #{e.sqlstate}" if e.respond_to?("sqlstate")
ensure
  # disconnect from server
  db_q.close if db_q
  db_r.close if db_r
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to do raw SQL or are extremely limited in the libraries you can use, an ORM, like [ActiveRecord](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/) could really cut down on the amount of SQL hair you need to deal with.

Comment: this is MySQL, so sequel can cut it down. Get real @hebe, if you can't write this query, use some help.

Comment: Since the query returns only the results of 1 user, I thought a solution which returns all users is not far. @three any hints on how to cut it down with sequel?

Comment: @Paul Rubel: I made a dump from the production and trying to do some evaluation on my data with Sequel Pro. That's why I sticked to raw SQL so far.. I actually never used Active Record apart from Rails.

Comment: sequel the gem I'm talking about.